# How to debug NullPointerException at apache.jena.queryExecutionFactory during create?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, jena, karaf

I am working with `org.apache.jena` with `karaf`. While trying to query my model I get a `NullPointerException` I printed all variables I use for creating the query and all(`queryString`, `inferedModel`) are not `null`.
Here is what my code looks like :

```
Model model = JenaEngine.readModel(inputDataOntology);
if (model == null) {
    return "model null !";
}
Model inferedModel = JenaEngine.readInferencedModelFromRuleFile(model, inputRule);
if (inferedModel == null) {
    return "inferedModel null !";
}
JenaEngine.updateValueOfDataTypeProperty(inferedModel, ns, "Peter", "age", 10);
JenaEngine.updateValueOfObjectProperty(inferedModel, ns, "Peter", "estFilsDe", "Femme1");
JenaEngine.createInstanceOfClass(model, ns, "Femme", "abc");
//query on the model
String prefixQuery = "PREFIX ns: <http://www.owl-ontologies.com/Ontology1291196007.owl#>\n" +
    "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>\n" +
    "PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>\n"+
    "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>\n";
String selectQuery = "SELECT ?user ?age WHERE {\n ?user ns:age ?age.\n }";
QueryExecution queryExecution = QueryExecutionFactory.create(prefixQuery+selectQuery, inferedModel);
ResultSet rs = queryExecution.execSelect();
List<String> users = new ArrayList();
while(rs.hasNext()) {
    QuerySolution qs = rs.next();
    Resource user = qs.getResource("user");
    users.add(user.getLocalName());
}
String results = "";
for(String user : users) {
    results+=user+" ";
}
return results;
```

I get a `NullPointerException` at the line where I initialize the `QueryExecution` variable.

Here is the stack trace of the error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.jena.query.ARQ.isTrue(ARQ.java:650)
        at org.apache.jena.sparql.lang.ParserBase.<init>(ParserBase.java:292)
        at org.apache.jena.sparql.lang.SPARQLParserBase.<init>(SPARQLParserBase.java:43)
        at org.apache.jena.sparql.lang.sparql_11.SPARQLParser11Base.<init>(SPARQLParser11Base.java:22)
        at org.apache.jena.sparql.lang.sparql_11.SPARQLParser11.<init>(SPARQLParser11.java:4974)
        at org.apache.jena.sparql.lang.ParserSPARQL11.perform(ParserSPARQL11.java:91)
        at org.apache.jena.sparql.lang.ParserSPARQL11.parse$(ParserSPARQL11.java:52)
        at org.apache.jena.sparql.lang.SPARQLParser.parse(SPARQLParser.java:34)
        at org.apache.jena.query.QueryFactory.parse(QueryFactory.java:147)
        at org.apache.jena.query.QueryFactory.create(QueryFactory.java:79)
        at org.apache.jena.query.QueryFactory.create(QueryFactory.java:52)
        at org.apache.jena.query.QueryFactory.create(QueryFactory.java:40)
        at fr.conceptit.tuto.web.Main.work(Main.java:71)
        ...
```

I'm deploying my application via Karaf maybe the problem comes from there. Here's a screenshot of my bundles list on Karaf. Notice that I added all Jena Jars.[Karaf Bundles list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRuvb.png)

Comment: So it happens inside `QueryExecutionFactory.create`? Catch the exception and print a stack trace

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-breakpoints.html

Comment: @JoakimDanielson indeed it happens inside `QueryExecutionFactory.create` . I added the stack trace for more information

Comment: NPE on `ARQ.isTrue` : ARQ isn't initialized properly;I can't see why not though. Which version are you running? (1) Have you repackaged the code at all? (2) If no, try adding `JenaSystem.init()`  before there has been any call to Jena.

Comment: @AndyS I don't unsderstand what you mean by repackaged the code I use `mvn clean install`, did you mean I have to use `mvn package`? I added `JenaSystem.init()` didn't do any better still have the same the NPE. Also maybe I wasn't clear enough but I'm using Karaf. I gave all the jena jars I'm adding a screenshot of my bundles maybe the problem comes from there.

Comment: Initialization is base on Java ServiceLoader mechanism. If Jena is packaged (e.g. shade plugin), then that has to combine the control files: https://jena.apache.org/documentation/notes/jena-repack.html. Classloaders also come into play if it is OSGi.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to @AndyS comment I was able to figure out a way to make it work. He pointed in the right direction saying :

> NPE on `ARQ.isTrue` : ARQ isn't initialized properly

Indeed that was the problem and I resolved it by initializing the `ARQ` and not `JenaSystem` as he suggested. Basically I added `org.apache.jena.query.ARQ.init()` before there has been any call to `Jena` and it worked.
Thanks again for your help and support.

Comment: `JenaEngine` is not part of Jena.

Comment: `JenaSystem.init()` is the right call rather than `ARQ.init` but both should work.

Comment: @AndyS you're actually right it was a typo I meant `JenaSystem` and not `JenaEngine` I edited my answer. Also I tried `JenaSystem.init()` didn't work for me. Maybe it comes from the fact that I'm using `Jena` with OSGI. Thanks again for your intel it helped me resolve my problem.

Comment: thanks. `org.apache.jena.query.ARQ.init()` also worked for me